# Include variables in seperate file in C?

Tags: c

I created a structure item:

```
typedef struct item
{
    char name[20];
    char desc[100];
    int lp;
    int shield;
    int weapon;
} item;
```

I need 36 of them so I create an array `item treasure[6][6];`

For each item I insert the data as so:

```
    strcpy(treasure[0][0].name, "name");
    strcpy(treasure[0][0].desc, "none");
    treasure[0][0].lp = 0;
    treasure[0][0].shield = 0;
    treasure[0][0].weapon = 200;
```

I do this 36 times and takes a lot of space in editor, my question: Can I put this in a separate .c/.h file maybe? I've been trying to but can't make it work.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Yes, you can do it in a separate file.  The chances are that isn't the best way of initializing the array, though.  You should look at how to initialize an array properly: `int array[6][6] = { { 1, 3, 9, 8, 3, 4 }, { 2, 9, 1, 0, -1, 7 }, … };` does it for `int`; you just need to replace numbers by a brace-enclosed initializer for each structure.

Comment: for 36 items why you are doing item treasure[6][6] and not item treasure[36]. Though both are correct but the latter approach is more understandable.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that use a file, like **init.h** with the following content

```
#include <string.h>
typedef struct item {
  char name[20];
  char desc[100];
  int lp;
  int shield;
  int weapon;
} item;

item treasure[1][1] = {
    {{.name = "name", .desc = "none", .lp = 0, .shield = 0, .weapon = 200}}};
```

In that way you must be able to initialize the struct of you matrix 6, 6 in another file, then you must be able to access it from the **main** program calling it like this:

```
#include "init.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("%s\n", treasure[0][0].name);
  return 0;
}
```

I hope this work for you, there a another ways to initialize structs, but this one is what I use more often. You can find more information here
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html

Comment: There should be no executable code in a header file at all, nor should there be any variable declarations. Global variables is very bad practice even if they aren't declared in a header file. This answer is plain bad advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn how to do proper C program design from the start, then this is how.

The correct way to do this is to create an item.h and a item.c file. Together they form a "code module" (or class, if you will).

Your header file item.h should contain the typedef and header guards. You should write an initialization function too.

```
// item.h
#ifndef ITEM_H
#define ITEM_H

#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  char name[20];
  char desc[100];
  int lp;
  int shield;
  int weapon;
} item_t;

void item_init (item_t*    item,
                const char name[20],
                const char desc[100],
                int        lp,
                int        shield,
                int        weapon);

#endif
```

You can then implement the init function in init.c:

```
// item.c
#include "item.h"

void item_init (item_t*    item,
                const char name[20],
                const char desc[100],
                int        lp,
                int        shield,
                int        weapon)
{
  strcpy(item->name, name);
  strcpy(item->desc, desc);
  item->lp = lp;
  item->shield = shield;
  item->weapon = weapon;
}
```

These two files, init.h and init.c are only concerned about the behavior of all `item_t` variables. You can expand them with more functions as you go. They do not and should not contain any actual data.

Now if you want to keep the data separate, you could create a separate pair of files for it like this:

```
// item_data.h
#include "item.h"

#define ITEMS_N 36

item_t* item_data_get (int item_n);
```

This is just a "getter" function that lets you access the data. The actual data is *encapsulated* in the .c file:

```
// item_data.c
#include "item_data.h"

static item_t items [ITEM_N] = 
{
  [0] = {.name="name", .desc="none", .lp=0, .shield=0, .weapon=200},
  [1] = ... // fill up data here
};

item_t* item_data_get (int item_n)
{
  return items[n];
}
```

If you later on want to change the data of a given item, you can do so by calling `item_init(item_data_get(n), ...);`